# Restrict nested container in jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i am working on an UI which will use this jquery sortable script (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/). I want to have a nested list, where i can only drag specific items into. Here is an example:

This is the nested list. What i do want do prevent is, that i can Drag

Second

Third

into the nested list.

```
<ol class="example">
        <li>First
            <ol class="nested1">
                <li>N1</li>
                <li>N2</li>
                <li>N2</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

I can initialize the sortable-list and configure possible actions with the isValidTarget: Option

```
$("ol.example").sortable({
    isValidTarget: function($item, container){
    // Here should be some kind to restrict the nested list
    }
});
```

I couldn't get it to work, because i don't know how to ask if the target is the nested list. Does anybody have an idea? Maybe its an easy question, but i'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The container has the target element as a property (`container.el`) which contains the jQuery element of the currently targeted container. You can use jQuery methods on that to determine if it's a valid target. I think the following is what you're trying to do.

```js
$("ol.example").sortable({
  isValidTarget: function($item, container) {
    if (container.el.hasClass("nested1")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<ol class="example">
  <li>First
    <ol class="nested1">
      <li>N1</li>
      <li>N2</li>
      <li>N2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly i was looking for. Can you tell me how to serialize the result? There is an option "serialize:" but i couldn't get it to work. Guess the whole syntax in javascript confuses me.

Comment: What do you imagine the output to look like? Maybe ask it as a separate question.